# Does CreateUserWizard call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

1) I assume that when CreateUserWizard.LoginCreatedUser is set to true, the control calls FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie, which in turn creates an authentication ticket (I’m pretty certain that the control doesn’t call FormsAuthentication.RedirectfromLoginPage )

2) From MSDN:

> When the LoginCreatedUser property is set to true, the user will be created and logged in at the end of the CreateUserStep step.

I don’t think that’s true, since when the page displays CompleteWizardStep, user is not yet logged in?!

thanx

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflector I can see that it calls `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);` right after the CreatingUser event fires.

So it logs the user in, but without a persistent cookie.

Comment: Won't user be logged in ( thus security context of the user will be created ) only on next postback, thus after page already displays CompleteWizardStep?!

Comment: Well, that's a possibility and I'm not sure.